# Plotting a set of parametric equations with several parameters in Julia

Tags: plot, julia, parametric-equations

To plot a circle of radius 2 centered at (1, 1) I do the following:

```
θ = 0:0.1:2π
x = 1 .+ 2cos.(θ)
y = 1 .+ 2sin.(θ)
plot(x, y, aspect_ratio=:equal)
```

However, if I want to plot a set of parametric equations with more than two parameters I cannot use this approach. How should one approach plotting parametric equations with more than one parameter in Julia? For instance, how can I plot the cone described by the parametric equations

```
x = r*cos(θ)
y = r*sin(θ)
z = r
```

where `r` and `θ` are the parameters?

I am imagining the final plot to look like in the below image that has been generated by entering `ParametricPlot3D[{r*Cos[t], r*Sin[t], r}, {r, -3, 3}, {t, 0, 2*Pi}]` in Mathematica.

[image]

Comment: How are you imagining the final plot to look?

Comment: @MichaelK.Borregaard I have updated the post with an image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works with the `plotly` and `pyplot` backends to `Plots` but not `gr`:

```
X(r,theta) = r * cos(theta)
Y(r,theta) = r * sin(theta)
Z(r,theta) = r

rs = range(0, 2, length=50)
ts = range(0, 2pi, length=50)

surface(X.(rs',ts), Y.(rs', ts), Z.(rs', ts))
```